# Android - Periodically broadcast an event

Tags: android

How do I periodically broadcast an event after user has installed my application.

I have implemented a broadcast receiver which will trigger a task onReceive. Now I need to periodically broadcast this event, so that the task will be executed periodically.

I know I need to use AlarmManager.
The code is somewhat like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, 0, 5*1000, pendingIntent);
```

Q1) Where do I place this code if I do not have any Activity? Do I implement this as a service?

Q2) What should be the intent-filter be for my manifest in such a "self created event"?

PS: Actually my current broadcast receiver is waiting for the connectivity change event.   The task is to periodically attempt/try to access the internet. But I cannot solely rely on connectivity change to trigger this task. That's why I need a timer which will either fire this event or trigger the method in onReceive().
I know in this case my intent-filter will be "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q1) Where do I place this code if I do not have any Activity?

You need to implement an activity. Nothing of your application will run on Android 3.1+ until the user has launched your activity.

So, you run this code:

- The first time the user runs your activity
- On a reboot (via a `BOOT_COMPLETED` `BroadcastReceiver`)
- In the future when the user runs your activity, if you have determined that no broadcasts have gone out in too long, because the user force-stopped your application

Also, get rid of `getApplicationContext()`, as you should not need it here.

> Q2) What should be the intent-filter be for my manifest in such a "self created event"?

You do not need one, as your `Intent` identifies the component.

Comment: ok.. if I got a PreferenceActivity, I have to do the piece of code in the onCreate method? Actually I have written 2 different classes for BroadcastReceiver(one for handling incoming SMS and one for connectivity change) Is it ok to separate them or put them together but do a if else to check on the getAction() and then implement this BOOT_COMPLETED broadcastreceiver?

Comment: @humansg: "I have to do the piece of code in the onCreate method?" -- that should work. "Is it ok to separate them or put them together but do a if else to check on the getAction() and then implement this BOOT_COMPLETED broadcastreceiver?" -- either separate or together is fine, that is up to you.